# how to do internationalization for wix bootstrapper

Tags: internationalization, wix

I have a `wix booststrapper` project, which cannot be localized like the normal WiX project.
If I extract the hard code string from the `booststrapper.wxs` file, then the compiler output errors:

> Light.exe : error LGHT0100: The localization identifier xxx has been duplicated in multiple locations. Please resolve the conflict

Has anyone some experience in boostrapper internationalization?

Would you give some suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

This issue is discussed here:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Votive-Light-LGHT100-error-when-more-than-one-localized-wxl-td7587802.html

In short, *if you include two or more .wxl files you will see this error*. The trick is to mark the extra localized wxl files as **Build Action = None** in the Properties window for the actual wxl files in the solution project tree.

If you are using a main one (or a copy) like RtfTheme.wxl, that one can remain as type Embedded Resource. This is the default type Visual Studio seems to assign wxl files added to the project but only one can ever be marked as such. So long as you have Payload elements that bring in the rest they do not need to be marked as Embedded Resource and, as experienced, it will fail the build if they are.

Additionally, the following post describes a very nice way to organize all these localization files: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/My-experiences-making-a-multi-language-bundle-td7208949.html

Comment: . I cannot use WiX project I18n process to internationalize the ShareFileWixBootstrapper project. I’ve tried other solution but it cannot work.